# How does swapping nodes in linked list works?

Tags: c++, linked-list, swap, singly-linked-list

Below is the code for swapping nodes without changing data. I wonder whether swapping the next pointers of nodes required? Will swapping the current nodes doesn't swap the next pointers? Why?

```
    void swapNodes(Node** head_ref, int x, int y) 
    { 

        // Nothing to do if x and y are same 
        if (x == y) 
           return; 

        Node **a = NULL, **b = NULL; 

        // search for x and y in the linked list 
        // and store therir pointer in a and b 
        while (*head_ref) { 

              if ((*head_ref)->data == x) { 
                   a = head_ref; 
              } 

              else if ((*head_ref)->data == y) { 
                   b = head_ref; 
              } 

              head_ref = &((*head_ref)->next); 
         } 

         // if we have found both a and b 
         // in the linked list swap current 
         // pointer and next pointer of these 
         if (a && b) { 

             swap(*a, *b); 
             swap(((*a)->next), ((*b)->next)); 
         } 
    } 

    void swap(Node*& a, Node*& b) 
    { 

         Node* temp = a; 
         a = b; 
         b = temp; 
    }
```

Thank You.

Comment: Maybe you could show us the swap function?

Comment: No matter what, the next pointers have to be swapped. Imagine a linked list a -> b -> c -> d. If you swap b and c without switching next, the list would be a -> c -> d.

Comment: But switching, you could get stuck in an infinite loop. a -> c-> c-> c....

Comment: @Ahamed Yasir Seeing questions in C and C++ that have been asked today it may be said that today is the day of the singly-linked list!:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> whether swapping the next pointers of nodes required?

Yes it is required because the original nodes take place in different positions of the list.

> Will swapping the current nodes doesn't swap the next pointers?

Yes, swapping current nodes doesn't swap the next pointers. Swapping current nodes means only swapping only pointers that point to the current nodes.

Consider for example the list

```
| A |next B| -> | B |next C| -> | C |next D| -> | D |next nullptr|
```

and let's assume that you need to swap nodes B and D. Then you'll get

```
                   ---------------------
                   |                    |
| A |next D| ... | B |next C| -> | C |next B| ... | D |next nullptr|
       |                                            |
       ----------------------------------------------
```

So after the first swapping the node A points to node D but node D "points" to nullptr. Nodes B and C will be lost if not to swap their data members next.

Thus you need also to swap their data members next

```
                   --------------------------
                   |                        |
| A |next D| ... | B |next nullptr|   | C |next B| ... | D |next C|
       |                                                 |
       ---------------------------------------------------
```

and as result you'll get

```
| A |next D| -> | D |next C| -> | C |next B| -> | B |next nullptr|
```

Comment: Is there any visual illustration available for this. If so kindly share it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Swapping the current nodes won't be enough.

When swapping a and b, their address is changed so their place in the list will be replaced

But you do not change the inner fields of each node.

Nodes Illustraion:

a - b - c - d

Let's take node a and c.

a->next == &b (True)

c->next == &d (True)

If we swap the nodes like this:

**c** - b - **a** - d

The address of node **c** and node **a** will change, but the list would look the same since their ->next values will not change

If we also swap the ->next values, the list will be really swapped

Comment: Can you explain me be taking real addresses. Thank You.